# Показ и скрыте столбцов в DataGrid динамически в зависимости от условия

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, mvvm

Мне нужно показывать и скрывать столбец компонента DataGrid в зависимости от условия.

Т.к. столбцы этого компонента не содержатся в логическом или визуальном дереве, я решил перенести нужный столбец в статические ресурсы

**View**

```
<UserControl Name="UserControl">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="ProblemColumn"
                            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsDisplayed, Source={x:Reference UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="myModels:SomeModel">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeViewModel}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="myModels:AnotherModel">
                                    <Border>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherItems}">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    ...
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ProblemColumn"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**
Тут моё проперти на которое я явно вешаю `false`

```
public bool IsDisplayed => false;
```

Таким образом моё проперти байндидтся успешно и возвращает нужное значение, но никаких изменений на UI не происходит, даже если я явно ставлю значение в `false` столбец всё равно отображается.

Что я мог пропустить?

Comment: А отлаживать пробовали? Поставить точку останова в  классе `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`и посмотреть по шагам как отрабатывает конвертация?

Comment: @Bulson, конкретно работу конвертера отслеживать не пробовал, т.к. он не кастомный, а из коробки

Comment: А почему бы во вьюмодели просто не создать свойство типа `bool` и привязаться к нему? По крайней мере так можно проверить, что сокрытие написанное вами в XAML работает как надо.

Comment: Я именно так и делаю, сейчас немного вопрос подправлю